# Replacing li bullets with backround image, IE 8 and 7

Tags: css

I am adding an image that acts like a bullet for a li:

```
.top_right li {
float: left;
width: 7em;
line-height: 100%;
background: url(images/thumbs.png) no-repeat top 4px left;
border-bottom: solid 1px #222;
margin-right: 1em;
padding: 5px 0 5px 1.3em
}
```

Any ideas why thumbs.png does not show in IE 8 and 7?

Comment: Please make a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or provide a link to your site if it's live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L5aQy/1/). I had to remove the `top 4px left` in the `bakcground` property for the image to show.

You have to either specify `top left` or `Xpx Ypx`, can't mix them up :).

Comment: You can only specify two background properties. One for the X-Axis and the Y-Axis. You can either specify those properties using top/center/left/right or using a value in pixels or any other css units. The X-axis (horizontal) property comes first.